# Is there a way to wirelessly send files to a raspberry pi through C# and without setting up connection on the RPi?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi

I am doing a school project where I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 to drive stepper motors. I'm in the process of researching for the interface program that will be run on a laptop and sends files of instructions for driving the motors. Is there any way that I can wirelessly connect to the Pi to send files by just running C# code as the program will be made in Unity? I've already looked at SSH, but it seems to require a GUI to function and prior knowledge of the IP address. I've also looked at some Bluetooth approaches where the pi was paired with the laptop, but it seemed there had to be a code inputted on the PC to verify the connection. Is there any way I could do this? I'm EXTREMELY new to this, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I think you should properly understand what you are asking. I interpret it as the following: I want to everyone to be able to send files to this RPi. SSH seems like your best option, i don't know where you found that SSH requires a GUI to function, this is incorrect.

Comment: That would probably depend on which OS you have on your RPi and what services are installed. E.g. if [samba is installed at RPi](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-samba/), you could probably just copy files over network (`File.Copy` should automatically use SMB when necessary but you should pay attention to authentication if necessary)

Comment: No GUI is required.  You just have to enable the Wifi at startup.  Raspberry PI 4 the configuration utility will help you configure.  Once enabled you can use FTP to transfer the files.  You would also have to enable a FTP service on the pi.

Comment: I guess [this](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html#remote-access) pretty much sums most obvious options

Comment: @WiktorZychla That helps, but it assumes the Pi is already connected to a network? Because the Pi will be enclosed in the product, there will be no way to access it to connect it to a network when it gets powered on. Again, I'm sorry if I'm missing something, but thank you for the help.